# How to get original image from Facebook Page by id: "651162398833115" or post_id: "650534342229254_651162398833115" Graph API?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using javascript to upload image on my Facebook page. After post request to Facebook page, I am getting `id: "651162398833115"` and `post_id: "650534342229254_651162398833115"` in return response.

My question is how can I get the url of my **original image** from Facebook page with the help of this two id's?

When I download the image manually (By right clicking on image) from my mac, all I got is a decreased quality and small dimension version of my uploaded image. Any suggestion?

This is what I am getting from the response:

```
{id: "651195638829791", post_id: "650534342229254_651195638829791"}
id: "651195638829791"
post_id: "650534342229254_651195638829791"
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Thanks!

**P.S**: I have tried couple of old existing ways to retrieve it, but none of them works.

Comment: The `images` field of the Photo object should contain all available sizes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment sir. Where can I find the `image` field? I have update my question with the response value.

Comment: I am talking about making a _new_ API request, using the photo ID you got returned from your upload call.

Comment: OK, got it. Let me try. :)

Comment: @CBroe Can you please take have a look to this question? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306230/transparent-image-background-become-white-after-posting-on-facebook-page-by-grap